# Firefox supports Sync, do we need MozBackup now?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

Now that FF has a sync feature, and assuming that there are folks who are ok with their data being stored on the cloud, does it still make sense to have a backup process using MozBackup?

**More background:**
I have a script that I use to take a zip of the complete profile folder, and move it from time-to-time onto my cloud backups. But, since FF Sync does all the backups (including preferences, open tabs, bookmarks, installed extensions, themes), I am not sure if I still need such a manual backup. as long as I click the "Sync now" button/menu item from time-to-time, can I rest assured that my offline backup is no longer needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the FF Sync does indeed sync the preferences, installed addons, etc, and all the open tabs on the first machine showed up in the "sync sidebar" on the second machine as well. BUT, the synced tabs lose a couple of important "features"

1. The order of the open tabs is messed up
2. The status of whether tab was pinned or not was also lost.

With the above, at this point, I feel I still need to continue with a full-backup of the profile folder.